# Android OnClick doesnt work for second layout

Tags: android, onclick

I have a Button which opens another layout when clicked. The second layout which opens also has a Button but somehow nothing happens on that Button when clicked.

My Activity:

```
package com.example.android.myapplicationo9;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static com.example.android.myapplicationo9.R.layout.layout2;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener         {

    public Button bt;
    public Button bt2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        final View textEntryViw = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout2,null);
        bt2 = (Button)textEntryViw.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                setContentView(layout2);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.button2:                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are setting new content view `layout2` for your `MainActivity`, you have to `initialize` views of new `layout2` again to use later.

**1.** Get your `Button` reference from `layout2`.

**2.** Set `onClick` listener to your `Button`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
case R.id.button:
{   
    setContentView(layout2);

    // Initialize button of layout2
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_of_layout2);

    // Set onClick listener
    button .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Layout2 Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"e",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
}
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

did you impl. on click method on both buttons? also - make sure you are not consuming the click / touch event thus "not passing" it further on throughout the view hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent for opening new Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class)
startActivity(intent);
```

Using setContentView only Changes the layout but you're still in the same class

Try using normal onClick methods and make sure you instantiate your views on the second Activity.